# Getting error when downloading latest nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install and activate NVIDIA drivers without Jockey?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59390/how-to-install-and-activate-nvidia-drivers-without-jockey)

I have a Geforce 7800 gfc. Whenever i try to download the official  driver from eh site, i get an error. i can download it perfectly well, but after its loading out it says "error in downloads/(something). Why does the keep happening? What driver should I get to play tf2? because from "additional driver" interface i downloaded the second to bottom one and i can't run tf2.
[image]